# convert HIghcharts chart image to png/jpg buffer to display in react-pdf

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, react-pdf

I have a react project displaying a Highcharts chart.
I want to export the chart into a PDF.

```
  const svg = scatterChartRef.current.chart.getSVG()
  const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(svg)

  const MyDocument = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Image src={imageBuffer} debug={false} />
        </View>
```

unfortunately this does not work, i'm assuming because react-pdf wants png or jpg image.

how can i convert my chart to png/jpg?

it seems the built in highcharts export methods only allow to trigger the download of a png or jpg, not provide a reference in code to a png/jpg buffer.

https://react-pdf.org/components#image

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting your chart to a buffer, you can convert the chart to a URL object.

```js
    const svgString = scatterChartRef.current.chart.getSVG();

    // Use DOMParser to parse new svg element from svgString
    const parser = new DOMParser(); 
    const svgElem = parser.parseFromString(svgString, "image/svg+xml").documentElement;

    // Use toDataURL extension to generate Base64 string
    const b64 = svgElem.toDataURL();

    return <Image src={b64} debug={false} />
```

Comment: i saw this solution before and couldn't figure it out.
`svgElem.toDataURL is not a function`

Comment: `documentElement` provides an `HTMLElement`, but `toDataURL` exists only on `HTMLCanvasElement`

Comment: @Julien Hmm, could you replace `.documentElement` with `.firstElementChild` or `.children[0]`? and try again.